# Passing function arguments to another function pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe df

```
  cust_id   order_date    
    1       2015-01-16      
    1       2019-12-03      
    2       2014-12-21      
    2       2015-01-10      
    1       2015-01-10
    3       2018-01-18
    3       2017-03-04
    4       2019-11-05
    4       2010-01-01
    3       2019-12-06
    3       2002-01-01
    3       2018-01-01
```

Active function will find out customers who have transacted in the past one month and have bought at least 3 times from a site.

```
 def active(month_before_current_month, freq):
         df['Frequency'] = df.groupby('cust_id')['order_date'].nunique()
         df = df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].max().loc[lambda x:x>= 
         (datetime.date.today() - 

          datetime.timedelta(month_before_current_month*365/12))].loc[lambda 
            x: 
             x['Frequency']>=3].reset_index().rename(columns= 
            {'order_date':'Most_recent_date'})
         return df
```

Output of active(1,3) function will be:(people who have bought 1 month before and have made at least 3 transactions till date)

```
    cust_id   Most_recent_date Frequency
     1         2019-12-03        3
     3          2019-12-06       5
```

Now I want to create another function which uses the function active to see after how much time we should send out fliers or marketing ads etc to these customers.

```
   def active_target(month_before_current_month, freq):
      df=active(month_before_current_month,freq)
      return df['Frequency'].mean()
```

This works fine. However I would like to pass the arguments active function itself.

When I do this:

```
       def active_target(**kwargs):
           df=active(month_before_current_month,freq)
           return df['Frequency'].mean()
```

**Calling active_target**

```
      active_target(active(1,freq))
          **I am getting error TypeError: active_target() takes 0 positional 
          arguments but 1 was given**
```

Can anyone help:

Comment: What did you call `active_target` with?

Comment: Pls check. edited

Comment: What's the function `active`? What does it return?

Comment: Pls check. active function is given. I have edited. had made typo error

Comment: Since you have already specified `active` inside, try calling `active_target(month_before_current_month,freq)`, python will look for `active` in the global scope.

Comment: 1. You're not passing a function object, you're passing the result of a function call. 2. You're not using `kwargs` anywhere...

Comment: TypeError: active_target() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
 for active(1,freq)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Pls suggest what i should type then

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You can do e.g. `def active_target(fun, args)` and inside `fun(*args)`, so that you call it with `active_target(active, args=(1, freq))`. Read the linked duplicates for inspiration.

Comment: Looking at your question again you just need `def active_target(active_fun, month_before_current_month, freq):`, inside it `df = active_fun(month_before_etc, freq)`, and call it as `active_target(active, 1, freq)`.

Comment: My code worked by calling active_target(active)......active_target was defined as  def active_target(active):
    df=active(m,freq)
   return df